# How to stop an app from draining the battery without uninstalling that app?

Tags: battery

I know how to identify which apps are using the battery, but I'm not sure what to do about it. There are some apps that I occasionally use but I don't want them draining the battery while I'm out and about. Is there any easy way to disable those apps without uninstalling them?

Comment: What kind of apps? The answer might be as simple as changing the settings in the app.

Comment: The most draining of the apps is Alipay (a payment service). I use it to buy things online, pay for taxis, and split the bill in restaurants. But some days I don't need it all and it drains 25% of my battery. Other than that, there are a few apps that each take up around 5% even when I don't use them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information. Comments are impermanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) it freezes the app when you are not explicitly using it. There is an experimental feature to make it work without root but I didn't try it since my phone is rooted.

There is also [Disable Service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice) that can disable single services. It requires root access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you meant [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice) for the second link.

Comment: yes exactly, I posted originally with my phone and when I edit with pc to fix link formatting I used [1] for the second link too.